# PDF signing using Golang

Tags: go, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, signing

I want to digitally sign a pdf that is created programmatically using Golang. Input will be bytes[] of pdf that is obtained after creation of it using go-wkhtmltopdf. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/go-pdf-sign/go-pdf-sign?

Comment: @DylanReimerink this is for validating a signed a pdf I think. But I need to create a signed pdf. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but you can generate a PDF with 1 library and sign it with another. I also came across this library https://github.com/unidoc/unipdf, which does generation of PDF's and also has examples of signing: https://github.com/unidoc/unipdf-examples/tree/v3/signatures. So that might better fit your needs. However, apparently you need a license to use it: https://github.com/unidoc/unipdf#license-key